# Vue Router shows null from the Created() method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'd like to access the Vue Router `this.$router` from the `created()` method from a component. However, it shows the `Cannot read property '$router' of null` error. It looks like the Vue Router isn't accessible from the `created()` method. Is there any alternative?

```js
created () {
  this.$router.push('/user')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

```
// this is inside your component
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next('/user');
},
created() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I'm currently doing. But, thought if we could do it from the `created()` method, it would be better.

Comment: Better how? You could also try inside `mounted()`.

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan Let me know if there's something to finish this one.

Comment: I'm considering your answer as the accepted one as this is the only solution for now.